# XF Rg.Plugins.Popup inputtransparent content PopUpPage

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, popup

I need advice. There is some way in PopupPage to make content InputTransparent = "True".

I'm trying to create an inputtransparent content pop-up page.
Unfortunately, InputTransparent = "True" does not work for x: Name = "GridRoot" in PopUpPage. It should go click on the Button in MainPage.

I have the following XAML code here:

[image]

here is the code-behind:
PopUpTest.cs

[image]

[image]

Comment: try ```<Grid InputTransparent="True" CascadeInputTransparent="True">```

Comment: If I set CascadeInputTransparent to true, I will lose interaction with all children. I only need to reach InputTransparent on GridRoot, not on the contents of this grid.

Comment: then change the color of the grid to transparent

Comment: I have already set the grid color to transparent. It still does not work

Comment: Please do not use images to show code. That makes it not searchable. Copy/paste the code into the question.

Answer (score 0):

Use RowDefinitions to explicitly say what areas are NOT part of the clickable content.

```
<Grid RowDefinitions="*,Auto,*" InputTransparent="True" CascadeInputTransparent="False" >
    <Grid Grid.Row="1" BackgroundColor="Red">
    ...
    </Grid>
</Grid>
```

This makes an outer 3-row grid. Inside that, on the second row (Row=1) is your visible content. Surrounded by Rows 0 and 2, which divide the extra space between them - but have no content, so they should not block input.

I don't think you need to put anything in rows 0 and 2, but if the above doesn't work, try:

```
...
    <BoxView Grid.Row="0" VerticalOptions="Fill" InputTransparent="True" />
    <Grid Grid.Row="1" BackgroundColor="Red">
    ...
    </Grid>
    <BoxView Grid.Row="2" VerticalOptions="Fill" InputTransparent="True" />
```

I don't know if the BoxView's need `HeightRequest` attributes. If above doesn't work, try adding `HeightRequest="999"` to them. The Grid logic will limit each BoxView's height to fit in its row.